# Can't connect to MYSQL container from Drupal container through drush

Tags: php, mysql, docker, drupal-8, drush

I try to figure out this problem since a long time now and I've got to admit that I'm out of responses.

Here is the case:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal

  drupal:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: drupal
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./web:/var/www/html/web:rw
      - ./vendor:/var/www/html/vendor:rw
      - ./drush:/var/www/html/drush
      - drupal-data:/var/www/html
      - ./php-conf/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    networks:
      - internal
      - external

  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.19.1-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    depends_on:
      - drupal
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - drupal-data:/var/www/html
      - ./web:/var/www/html/web:rw
      - ./nginx-conf/snippets/self-signed.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/snippets/self-signed.conf
      - ./nginx-conf/snippets/ssl-params.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/snippets/ssl-params.conf
      - ./nginx-conf/sites-available/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./ca-certificates/qiminfo-docker.dev+4.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/qiminfo-docker.dev+4.pem
      - ./ca-certificates/qiminfo-docker.dev+4-key.pem:/etc/ssl/private/qiminfo-docker.dev+4-key.pem
    networks:
      - external

networks:
  external:
    driver: bridge
  internal:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  drupal-data:
  db-data:
```

Dockerfile (only for drupal container)

```
FROM drupal:8.9.2-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add mysql-client && apk add openssh
```

I manage all dependencies via the mounted files in volumes (it works nice btw), but when I run drush through my host machine or through the container it doesn't see the Drupal instance (neither root or database) and I get the classic error message in this case ...

```
In BootstrapHook.php line 32:
                                                                      
  [Exception]                                                         
  Bootstrap failed. Run your command with -vvv for more information.
```

But, I use the Dockerfile to get mysql-client installed on drupal container and to allow connection from drupal container to mysql container. And when I try to connect to mysql (which has 'mysql' hostname) container database it works !

```
➜ docker exec -it drupal sh
/var/www/html # mysql -u drupal -p drupal -h mysql 
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 13
Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [drupal]>
```

The question is:

Why drush doesn't has access to mysql server container while mysql-cli does the job fine ?!

Please help T-T